# group by for all rows and some selected group by values?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

There are two tables: Products and Orders, in 1-N relation.

Creating a group by on products, with sum of order values is straight-forward, and gives something like:

```
Product1    1000
Product2    2000
Product3    1400
Product4    1600
```

But, I need to list only a few selected products (can be typed inside query design view), and put sum of all others in the last row, like this:

```
Product1    1000
Product3    1400
Other       3600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a field expression to your query ...

```sql
IIf([YourField] In ('Product1','Product3'), [YourField], 'Other')
```

Then you can `GROUP BY` that field expression and sum the order values.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to parametrize those values? To create a form and bind "in" part to some form input, in a simple way? But not using a fixed number of parameters, In([Forms]![QueryForm].[Column1], [...] )

Comment: `In ()` will not accept a parameter for the value list.  You could use VBA to modify the query's SQL based on the form input.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a field or table for translation of your products into your desired products for output.

The better option is to use a table like:

```
Product-Name    Product-Name-For-Output
Product1        Product1
Product2        Other
Product3        Product3
Product4        Other
```

Then join the new table to your query and remove `Product-Name` field from output and add `Product-Name-For-Output` field.

The advantage of this solution is that you just need to change your data and not your query to add or remove products from the group `Other`.